# むやみに equivalents : 勝手に vs よく考えないで

Tags: word-choice

Working on practice problems for JLPT N1,

had the following sentence:

**むやみに**　知らない人に話しかけないほうがいい。

Correct answer per the book is よく考えないで.

Incorrect answer per the book 勝手に

Can someone tell me why the former is to be preferred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bit of a nuanced difference there.

- `勝手に` is acting without *caring* about (the effect on) others.
- `むやみに` however is acting without *thinking* about the consequences.

So, the answer `よく考えないで` matches `むやみに`'s meaning of doing something *without considering* if it might (e.g.) inconvenience others. In contrast, using `勝手に` would mean doing it *without caring* if it inconveniences others.

EDIT: would be nice if you explain what I"m getting wrong when you downvote.

Comment: It wasn't me... I'm just leaving the question open a little longer to see if any other answers appear there's anything else on the nuance I'm missing. I think the gap in my comprehension was in the use of むやみに -- in that I think I misunderstood its usage. It would be definitely complete if you could give examples where the 2 are definitely not interchangeable.

Comment: 「勝手に~するな」は、「他の人の許可なく」といった、もう少し強い意味のような気はします。「勝手な人」だとselfishですが。